# Globally turn off Colorama colour codes

Tags: python, colorama

Python's [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) is fantastic for dressing up terminal output:
[image]

As you can see, this will add ANSI codes and make colours appear, even if using the logging module to stdout. I'm doing so with statements like this:

```
logging.info(f"{Fore.CYAN}Query received from {current_user.username}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

However if I were to point the logging module to write to a file, then I'd get a whole bunch of ANSI codes everywhere which I obviously do not want.

Short of writing `if` statements everywhere to suppress colorama if logging to file is turned on (or writing a logging function that does the same), is there a way to turn off colorama globally at the top of a script?

Comment: Its readme says "To stop using colorama before your program exits, simply call deinit(). This will restore stdout and stderr to their original values, so that Colorama is disabled." -- did you already try that?

Comment: yes I did. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily replace the `Fore`, `Back`, and `Style` namespaces with ones that contain empty strings for the constants.

```
class DummyFore:
    BLACK=RED=GREEN=YELLOW=BLUE=MAGENTA=CYAN=WHITE=RESET=''

saved_Fore, Fore = Fore, DummyFore

logging.info(f"{Fore.CYAN}Query received from {current_user.username}{Style.RESET_ALL}") # should insert empty strings for the colour codes
Fore = saved_Fore
del saved_Fore # just to be thorough
```

It should also work to wrap the save-restore logic in a context manager:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def without_colorama():
    global Fore
    saved_Fore, Fore = Fore, DummyFore
    yield
    Fore = saved_Fore
    # since saved_Fore is now a local, no need to `del`

with without_colorama():
    logging.info(f"{Fore.CYAN}Query received from {current_user.username}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

In all the example code I have only handled the `Fore` namespace; the others are left as an exercise.